# How do I make script to teach machine how to play game like this? (Youtube)

Tags: machine-learning, lua

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXe-BTXAnQ9VaQQZnlC608A

This guy made machine learning script and teach machine 
how to play Super Mario and complete each level.

There's FAQ document in the description of every his video
that he's using LUA to make this script but I don't even know where 
to start and can't find any tutorial on youtube how to make something like this

My goal is make machine learning script for other games and see 
the machine learning how to play and complete various levels

Could you please guide me where I can start and what I should learn to make script like this?

and I prefer programming language easier to learn if there is other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

- Are you a beginner programmer? If so, diving into machine learning will prove to be frustrating. You need a solid foundation first in programming principles.
- The next level would be to use a machine learning library. The core ML algorithms are then already written and optimized and you just need to learn how to integrate them into your own programs. Don't be fooled though - to do this well still requires a solid understanding of ML principles. There are existing libraries for Lua and Python. That is a good place to start.
- I would consider looking at Andrew Ng's *introductory* material (book and videos) on ML. Warning! He knows what he is talking about and does offer up quite a bit of advanced material as well. Don't start with that.
- There are excellent, advanced books on the subject that explain the mathematical principles behind the apparent magic of ML. If you already did all of the above and are still sticking with it, then this would be the way to go next. You could work on your own implementation of ML and apply that to any domain.

I'm gonna guess that you are at the first bullet point still. Be patient. Learn to program well. Get exposure to ML ideas. Plan on that video game ML application some years from now.

Comment: wtf some years from now? is that that much difficult like that? WOW and among lua and python which one do you recommend more for newbie?